# NGINX and Clickonce

Tags: nginx, clickonce, nginx-location

I am trying to get my NGINX website to work with Microsoft clickonce. I have the web site able to display the standard microsoft clickonce install page, but when I get to the Install page on my website and click the install button, nothing happens. I believe at that point it is supposed to download an EXE, which it doesn't do. Does anyone have any experience in getting clickonce to work with NGINX and what is required? Any information about setting correct directives, location, configuration, mime types or whatever else may be required.

Here is my current config file. I am new to NGINX, so perhaps it is something I am doing wrong with the location, or...?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/MyWebSite;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name MyWebSite.com www.MyWebSite.com;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/MyWebSite.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/MyWebSite.error.log;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /Application/MyApp/ {
            try_files /Application/MyApp/publish.htm /Application/MyApp/setup.exe /application/MyApp/MyApp.application;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
    types {
            application/x-ms-application .application;
    }
```

}

Comment: This is missing quite a bit of information.  What deployment strategy are you using? Are file permissions correct? What does the 'install button' do? Do you have the application installed already on the computer?

Comment: I'll apologize up front. I am new to NGINX, so I'm not sure what to ask, as in you don't know what you don't know. I added a little more info to my question in hopes that may help. I can add my current config file, but I'm not sure that will be of any help, because it's really pretty basic at this point, and might just muddy up the question.

Comment: Also, I think you may need IE to 'use' a clickOnce the way you are trying to use it. (There may be plugins for other systems).

Comment: Thanks for the comment SH. I did see someone using Tomcat successfully, so I'm thinking this is also possible in NGINX. I ended up adding my config to the post, in hopes that it helps, because I'm likely doing something wrong in it.